# Cannot retrieve a querystring parameter. 

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

An example of the Request URL: `http:\\localhost\ChatWindow.aspx?username=sly_chandan`

My webmethod is listed below:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static List<PrivateMessage> GetMessages()
{
    List<PrivateMessage> getMsgsList = (List<PrivateMessage>)HttpContext.Current.Application["PrivateMessages"];
    var msgs = getMsgsList.Where(x => x.fromUsername == HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString() && x.toUsername == HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"]);
    return msgs.ToList();
}
```

I cannot seem to retrieve the querystring parameter.

Comment: maybe you mean || instead of &&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the querystring, you should simply be able to change your method to look like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static List<PrivateMessage> GetMessages(string username)
{
    List<PrivateMessage> getMsgsList = (List<PrivateMessage>)HttpContext.Current.Application["PrivateMessages"];
    var msgs = getMsgsList.Where(x => x.fromUsername == HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString() && x.toUsername == username;
    return msgs.ToList();
}
```