# Trying to access querystring value in web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I am trying to pass querystring value from one of the gridview item on click to another web page 'Uncoated_wire.aspx.cs', here I want to use that value inside a web method 'GetCustomers' .how to achieve that.
tad.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#THistory").click(function (event) {               
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#pdfFormInsideL1").hide();
                document.getElementById('<%=gvCustomers.ClientID%>').style.display = 'block';
                //$("#gvCustomers").show();
                $("#gvCustomers").attr("visibility", "visible");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TDC.aspx/GetCustomers",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var customers = xml.find("Table");
                var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    var customer = $(this);
                    //$("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").text($(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
                    ***$("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href", "Uncoated_Wire.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text()).attr('target', '_blank');***                    
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("REVISION").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("REVISION_DATE").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("P_GROUP").text());
                    $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
```

The highlighted star mark code line is used for passing value to  another web page uncoated_wire.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TDC_NO_VAL = Request.QueryString["Id"];
        hdn_val.Value = TDC_NO_VAL;
}


 [WebMethod]
        public static string GetCustomers()
    {
 hdn_val.Value = TDC_NO_VAL;
    }
```

In this web method I want to access that querystring parameter how to do that.Any idea wouldd be appreciated

Comment: you grab the the value from the request, just like you would in a page.

Comment: @mason how can u show .I have tried but getting errror.

Comment: You haven't shown your attempt or explained what error you're getting. That information belongs in your question.

Comment: @mason i have edit the question .how i am trying to get value in web method using hidden field .But getting error an object refrence is required for  non-static field..What would be the best approach.

Comment: You can't access a variable declared in another method. And Page_Load doesn't run for a WebMethod. You need to access Request.QueryString directly in your WebMethod.

Comment: @mason But how could we access  Request.QueryString directly in WebMethod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot retrieve a querystring parameter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427398/cannot-retrieve-a-querystring-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to get querystring from WebMethod.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCustomers()
{
    string strId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Id"];
    //dosomething    
}
```

Hope this helps!